# Creating an interactive map with HTML5,CSS3,Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, maps

I'm going to build and develop  an **interactive map of my school**.Map should be fully interactive where there should be clickable event.When a user wants to view the laboratory details,he/she should be click on the specific lab region.So that **clickable events,pop ups** should be applied to the map.

I have started this task with SVG/CSS and HTML5.And also I have so far searched it and found this interesting link for this.
**http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/**

If anybody know a better **tutorial or a site** to accomplish my task,it will be very grateful.If so please share some tutorial/url links

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I've been searching on this I found this interesting site where u can draw your own svg images. http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

You can easily get the svg code for the diagram.

And easily we can integrate click events,whatever java script code with the svg image. cheers!!

Comment: the link is not working, the new link to the tool is at: https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html

Comment: new link also not working... now its this: https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit

Answer (score 3):

Try [FLDraw Interactive Image Creator Lite](http://fldraw.com/), it's free,
use it to create a mobile-friendly interactive map of your school, I have used it
for some of my projects (not the Lite edition, because I needed some advanced features too)

It's really simple:

1. Start a new project and choose your school map image as your base image
2. Use the Shape tool to create a hotspot
3. Double-click your new shape element to open the events window
4. Select an event type (tooltip, image infobox, HTML info box, ...)
5. Save the project and Publish to HTML5

open the created HTML file in your browser.

[Sample Interactive Map from their homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVWN0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [answer] a question.